# Cancel multiple timeouts set to an ID

Tags: javascript, timeout, settimeout

I'm not quite sure of the mechanics of this problem, but I'm trying to have a single setTimeout set to a variable ID that I can easily cancel using clearTimeout. But, if setTimeout gets triggered twice before clearTimeout, things go wacky.

Example:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_settimeout2

Clicking "Try It" twice and then "Stop the Alert" twice, the function of set timeout still gets called. Likewise, I'm not sure why Try It would trigger the function twice considering the event is saved to a variable that is getting overwritten.

Any idea of what's going on here?

Comment: The second time you call `setTimeout()`, the reference to your first timer is lost, but it's still there (somewhere) and will run. When you click "Stop", only the second timeout (the only one you have a reference to) is disabled. It's basically the same thing if you call `setTimeout()` without storing it in a variable in the first place.

Comment: So, given this knowledge, one way to "fix" the issue is to only call setTimeout via a function that clears the Timeout before it's called. It will reset the timer each time and only trigger the timeout target function once, but at least the clear will work properly.

[Try it here.](http://jsbin.com/ecocol/2/)

Comment: Or you just use more than one reference: Multiple variables or an array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like MCL has explained, you're loosing the reference to previous timeout, since a new assignment will override it.

What you can do is to put the timeouts to an array:

```
var myTimer = [];

function myFunction () {
    myTimer.push(setTimeout(function(){alert("Hello")},3000));
}

function myStopFunction () {
    clearTimeout(myTimer.pop());
}
```

This way you can cancel the last set timeout when clicking `Stop the alert` button.

A live demo at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z8suS/).

Comment: To put it another way, one has to click "stop" as many times as he clicked "start" in order to prevent any timer from firing.

Comment: Perfect. Between this and the example I linked above, I think that covers the behaviors I could need. Thanks!

Comment: @dhelm You're wellcome. You can also cancel timeouts in a specific order by using array index instead of always just pop out the last one.